# Show OneToOne relationship and inlines of the declaring model in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Let's say I have the following models

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Store(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Owner)

class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        choices=WEEKDAYS
    )
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hours = models.TimeField()
```

How could I put all of these models on the same admin page?
Right now, I'm only inlining the store in the owner model like this

```
class StoreInline(models.StackedInline):
    model = Store

class OwnerAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    model = Owner
    inlines = (StoreInline,)
```

But would like to do something like this

```
class StoreInline(models.StackedInline):
    model = Store

class OpeningHoursInline(models.StackedInline):
    model = OpeningHours

class OwnerAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    model = Owner
    # Here, in a perfect world, Django would follow the OneToOneField.
    inlines = (StoreInline, OpeningHoursInline, )
```

I tried using nested inlines with two different libraries but the display was somewhat broken. Since a it's a one to one relationship, I'm sure there's a trivial solution.

Thanks!